# How to set foreign keys

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am getting foreign keys as `NULL`, Someone told me that it is due to the fact that i am not setting its value , but I think when I refer it to a primary key it should adopt that primary key values.

Here is the code I am using to create table and then inserting:

```
sql="Create Table if not exists Machine "+
    "( InstallationDate varchar(100) not null , Machine_id int  ,FOREIGN KEY (Machine_id) REFERENCES machineInfo(Machineid),"+"Protocol_ID int ,"+ 
            "FOREIGN KEY (Protocol_ID) REFERENCES communicationprotocol(ProtocolID),Port_ID int ,FOREIGN KEY (Port_ID)"+
    " REFERENCES porttype(PortID) "+ 

    ",SerialConfigurationID int, NetworkConfigurationID int) ENGINE=InnoDB";

     stmt.execute(sql);


    System.out.println("Table Created"+"\n");
       sql="Insert into Machine (InstallationDate) values(?)";
       PreparedStatement pstmtmain=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         pstmtmain.setString(1, Installationdate);

         pstmtmain.execute();
```

Please help me correct this.

Answer (score 1):

You have some serious misconceptions on how SQL and databases work. A foreign key is a constraint which means: the values used here should be either `NULL`, or they should be one of the values in the primary key (or unique key) of the target table.

The target `machineInfo` table can contain hundreds, thousands, millions or - if you're lucky - billions of machines. How do you think the database can decide for you which `machine_id` to use when you execute an insert like:

```
Insert into Machine (InstallationDate) values(?)
```

It can't. **You** need to tell it which value to use, and if you don't then the server will simply use `NULL` to signify *unknown/not set*. If you specified a value that doesn't exist in the `machineInfo` table, then the insert will fail as the constraint is not fulfilled.

So use:

```
Insert into Machine (machine_id, InstallationDate) values(?, ?)
```

And specify the `machine_id` it needs to use.

Comment: I want give it a value of primary key , how can i get the primary key value

Comment: @user3909276 When you insert an entry into `Machine`, I assume you know which `MachineInfo` record it needs. Use the id of that record.

Comment: yes it needs machineid corresponding to machine name , but how can i get the value of that id .

Comment: @user3909276 I don't know, it is your application. You either select it from the table based on some condition only you can know, or you obtain it using the `getGeneratedKeys` facility when inserting a record into `machineinfo`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to avoid null values in the foreign keys?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Machine (
    InstallationDate       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL                          ,
    Machine_id             INT          NOT NULL                          ,
    Protocol_ID            INT          NOT NULL                          ,
    Port_ID                INT          NOT NULL                          ,
    SerialConfigurationID  INT                                            ,
    NetworkConfigurationID INT                                            ,
    FOREIGN KEY (Machine_id)  REFERENCES machineInfo(Machineid)           ,
    FOREIGN KEY (Protocol_ID) REFERENCES communicationprotocol(ProtocolID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Port_ID)     REFERENCES porttype(PortID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In another way, you need to insert the values ​​of the foreign keys if you do not want null values.

```
INSERT INTO Machine (InstallationDate, Machine_id, Protocol_ID, Port_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Actually i donot want any null value , i want for example if machine_id is a foreign key then i want it to have value of machineid the primary key it refers , how can i do that

Comment: @user3909276 **You** need to **set** its value, otherwise it is **NULL**. How else would the database know which machine you are inserting for.